# Surveil a program, and do something if it dies?

Tags: bash, pid

I have a program running on a little Raspberry Pi. Is there any way for me to write a bash script that is always checking if the program is running or not? If the program crashes, the script does something (e-mails me, for example).

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's easier if the bash script launches it in the first place. Does it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's one script launching the program, and another script running in the background checking if the program launched by the first script is still running.

Comment: Could the first script launch the program indirectly, via the second script?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
task() {
  echo "process died."
}
/bin/pidof <process-name>
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
  task
fi

A script like this and properly timed crontab should do. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest implementation would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  program "$@"
done
```

Basically, the script runs `program`, and then immediately re-runs it if it exits. It's simple, efficient, and robust.

If you want the script to watch something already running, and restart it, then you have a more difficult task. You have to grep the output of `ps`, or some such, and that means patterns, text manipulation, and possibly some magic. It also means regular polling, which is inefficient, and/or means there will be a noticeable gap between one process exiting, then new one starting.

Alternatively, you could have a "program.pid" file somewhere, which make life easier, but you still need to check that the process with the given PID is the program it ought to be, and it's still all about polling.

---

Aside: You might like to consider setting your program up as a system service. I'm not sure what Rasbian uses, but both Upstart and Systemd can handle services that must be restarted when they die.

Comment: Thank you! But I need the program to do more than just restart the program that dies. It needs to warn me, some other things. Say I save the programs PID in a file, how do I check if the pid in that file is running or not?

Comment: @Paolo look in `/proc/$PID`.